# Char array to bit

Tags: c++, массивы

У меня есть вектор содержащий в себе char(hex).

```
    std::vector<char> buffer;
```

После этого я хочу получить определённые элементы этого вектора. Для этого я забираю нужные мне элементы из вектора таким образом:

```
    char testSize[4];
    testSize[0] = buffer[byteCounter - 1];
    testSize[1] = (buffer[byteCounter - 2]);
    testSize[2] = (buffer[byteCounter - 3]);
    testSize[3] = (buffer[byteCounter - 4]);
```

Эти данные представляют собой значение времени. Для этого я хочу перевести получившиеся данные testSize в int, а после в bitset.
Каким образом можно совершить такое преобразование?

Comment: что Вы имеете ввиду под битовой формой?

Comment: @Валентин Чикунов Ваш фрагмент кода совершенно не понятен, и не понятно, что вы собираетесь сделать.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow я хотел представить testSize в виде bitseta, Просто в дальнейшем для получившегося значения, я буду выделять определённый бит

Comment: @ВалентинЧикунов Отредактируйте вопрос так, чтобы был понятно, что вы собираетесь сделать, и чтобы код имел какой-то смысл.

Comment: @ВалентинЧикунов Непонятно, как выглядят ваши данные.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow в векторе хранятся hex значения. А после я достаю необходимые по индексу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

кажется вам нужно работать с самими битами. к примеру так

```
testSize[0] = buffer[byteCounter - 1];
```

и если `testSize[0]` равно `0x23`

```
0x23 = 0010 0011

0x02 = 0000 0010 // нужный бит
```

и если сделаете так

```
 testSize[0] & 0x02 =
 0x23 & 0x02 =
 0010 0011 & 0000 0010 =
 0000 0010 > 0
```

получим

```
 if ((testSize[0] & 0x02) >0 ) ...
```

Проверяете значении `0x01` `0x02` `0x04` `0x08` `0x10` `0x20` `0x40` `0x80`